# VSCode devcontainer MacOS- clone repo in container volume

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, docker-volume, docker-desktop, vscode-remote

I'm using *VSCode Remote* extension in my *MacBook Pro*. I'm trying to `Clone repository in Container Volume`, but it failed because of:

```
ERROR: for app  Cannot start service app: Mounts denied: 
The path /workspaces/my_project is not shared from the host and is not known to Docker.
You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> Resources -> File Sharing.
See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac for more info.
```

I added this path to the Docker File Sharing:

[image: Docker file sharing]

And now the workspace is loaded, but I don't have permissions to the files!

Running `touch foo` or creating it from the VSCode UI returns an error `touch: cannot touch 'foo': Permission denied`.

```
Unable to write file 'vscode-remote://dev-container+7b227265706f7369746f727950617468223a2268747470733a2f2f6769746875622e636f6d2f436865636b6d6172784465762f636f7272656c6174696f6e5f656e67696e652e6769742f747265652f7371756164222c22766f6c756d654e616d65223a225f5f554e495155455f5f222c22666f6c646572223a22636f7272656c6174696f6e5f656e67696e65222c22636c6f6e65496e666f223a7b2275726c546f436c6f6e65223a2268747470733a2f2f6769746875622e636f6d2f436865636b6d6172784465762f636f7272656c6174696f6e5f656e67696e652e676974222c22726566223a227371756164227d2c22696e7370656374566f6c756d65223a66616c73657d/workspaces/my_project/foo' (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/workspaces/my_project/foo')
```

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if perhaps you have found a solution? I have stumbled myself in this today and it would be a very good step for me to increase I/O speed

Comment: It is working for me, but I don't remember how I solved this...
I set "Use gRPC FUSE", don't know if it is related.
Also let's make sure you're in the latest version of Docker, maybe a restart will help...

Comment: Wierd, cause I was looking now at the docs of vscode and says that it's "Not yet supported in Codespaces or when using Clone Repository in Container Volume" at the workspaceFolder section https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference. I tried to enable the Use gRPC FUSE, but it changed nothing. Anyway I will patiently wait for vscode to release a supporting version of it. Thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry for that, I don't have the time to research how it is working on my machine

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The settings dialog didn't allow me to add `/workspaces` to the allowed paths.

The only solution that worked for me was to set the root path `/`.

**Update:** I also had configured a bind mount in the docker-compose file. After removing that bind mount and rebuilding the container, the dev container started without changing anything in the settings.